# How do I move vendor folder outside the app in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have several apps built with CakePHP 3.x. Every app has `vendor` folder, which contains cakephp core and plugins. Contents of this folder is the same in every project, and this folder contains (in my case with couple of plugins installed) almost 2600 files.

I've tried to move this folder outside the apps and create symlinks. Also I've tried to create symlinks to subfolders inside it. Both methods generate errors with include/require paths.

The second method seems to be preferable, as I'm able to install additional plugins to different projects.

I think it is a good idea to have core folder in separate place, to simplify core update in all apps at once and save disk space, but how do I do this?

I have WAMP server on developer machine and windows server/IIS as production.

thanks.

**upd:** now both of my projects structure look like:

```
\app_X\
-- bin\
-- .....
-- vendor\
----- aura\
----- cakephp\
----- smarty\
----- symphony\
----- autoload.php
----- cakephp-plugins.php
```

and I'm asking about structure like

```
\_cake\                      /* contains cake core & core plugins */
-- aura\
-- cakephp\
-- smarty\
-- symphony\


\app_X\
-- bin\
-- .....
-- vendor\
----- ~aura\                  /* symlink to ..\..\_cake\aura */
----- ~cakephp\
----- ~smarty\
----- ~symphony\
----- appX_Plugin_Y\          /* regular folder */
----- autoload.php            /* regular file */    
----- cakephp-plugins.php
```

Comment: ok guys, thanks for closing my question, but you pointed to "Move the whole folder" question, but I asked about "creating symlinks". it's not the same. In my case composer options remain different for different projects, and I'm able to install different plugins. The question was about symlinks handling and saving disk space.

Comment: The problem still remains the same as explained in the linked answer. The linked answer provides yet another solution and from experience I can tell you working with symlinks the way you intend to do so will just cause you more pain and frustration especially when moving the project(s) to another server and setting it up somewhere else. Just use composer and you'll avoid a lot of trouble. I don't know what your problem with spending some disk space on this is. You just create yourself a lot more trouble and work. You're making up a problem where none is.

Comment: In case you have tens of projects and you like to manually update core every time, then you don't have problem. Linked answer suggest to create a folder for all plugins and dependencies, like `union`, and i'm talking about only core plugins, which are default in `cake`. There is nothing tricky about moving such project with symlinks to new server, just copy project, and then copy shared folder contents to `vendor` dir, or use archive, which follows symlinks.